# Why doesn't setTimeout work for async action creators in React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, redux, react-redux

I'm learning react redux from [here](https://github.com/happypoulp/redux-tutorial/blob/master/07_dispatch-async-action-1.js) but don't understanding this part:

```
var asyncSayActionCreator_0 = function (message) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        return {
            type: 'SAY',
            message
        }
    }, 2000)
}
```

> But then our action creator would not return an action, it would
>   return "undefined". So this is not quite the solution we're looking
>   for.

Why wouldn't this work? I thought setTimeout returns a ID for the timeout, not undefined.

Comment: It would if you did `return setTimeout(...`. If no `return` statement is hit, the function returns `undefined`.

Comment: so the whole thing would work if I used `return`?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. It would return an ID but you would never get the return value of the `setTimeout` callback. Meaning, you could never access the `{ type: 'SAY', message }` object.

Comment: where does the `{ type: 'SAY', message }` object get returned to then??

Comment: The abyss. Nothing can reference it.

Comment: nowhere, `setTimeout` callback does not return anything. you would need to dispatch inside `setTimeout` using a `redux-thunk` or something

Comment: You can use the [Redux Thunk middleware](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) for async actions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons that code wouldn't work:

1. Because that function does not have a return function (looks like a typo).
2. Even if it returns a `number`, it's not an action (an object), and you also need a reference to the "dispatch" function to send the action to the store. Later in the tutorial they show how this is called: https://github.com/happypoulp/redux-tutorial/blob/master/09_middleware.js#L61 (redux expects the action to always be an object, and redux-thunk executes the action if it is a function).

By using the thunk middleware, you generate what's called an "effect". That effect is external to the state of your application. In functional programming this is called an "impure" function.

As a side note, that tutorial doesn't look really good. I'd recommend something more like this tutorial: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: It's not a typo, the link he's reading explicitly says why this won't work.

Comment: Yeah, but doesn't look like a very didactic or good explanation why it won't work (see my point #2).

Comment: "But then our action creator would not return an action, it would return "undefined"" that's exactly correct.. it's perfectly well explained.